# how to generate oauth 1.0 signature using hmac-sha256 in c#

Tags: c#, oauth, signature

how to generate oauth 1.0 signature using hmac-sha256 in c#
The key contains like below.

```
consumerKey
Token_ID
oauth_timestamp
oauth_nonce
realm
version 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to play with HS256 tokens and I hope this can help you:

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            string IDTokenStr = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkJKUHFUQ2ZIc1BWcTJfck5TNWxwbXciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.zPaZ_-fZW-YOywsip_s9vks54m0iLUB_XBlevPVe4qT6xRAGFnEmho1Zvsbm5w5MamzKbJhu_GGXARAAFuttgCW_AEPXfFrgsPwz41IIpW7uUmC7ZKc2SpE1zKGJ3GqZ3QI9LYVOzPyUwJyBsvcYfiWR2MM_8AtJfpO2YpjSiBcSDhtdzxXtMwrMDxVEJ15EGqg-9t3xngk8ymDEJj-D5L_MSJSxjMrKv0hYee2a0NdocLEQlk385WDWplhPH2UQ1za0Q7GA913Y4_rQ6FTje7cbtaP1A_DahQJhOdDEpqsGXdPMEs-eRYsw2EbpXcJZqjB9_MaO-rLiXMmME2SrRQ";
            string AccessTokenStr = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkJKUHFUQ2ZIc1BWcTJfck5TNWxwbXciLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1ODQ3MzIyNTUsImV4cCI6MTU4NDczNTg1NSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZGVudGl0eXNlcnZpY2UubG9jYWw6NjAwMSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImltcGxpY2l0Zmxvd2NsaWVudCIsInN1YiI6IlVzZXJJRDEyMzQ1NiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU4NDczMjI1NCwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwiZW1haWwiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.iTIOq-8AmCKpogNUdmHMoDnq4ka836PTQR-PGttjZgJvKaB-WoqBwVSxx9_ABnzCZ9Tb-06RFyMgseICLkSqft3S0O5n2z7SXV8R2JbgjEJ74qzuLf6N_Xh5vhI1e4xkJp0j04_O_zL64LZM3ofUFqafjog5xPF85MEmVVFxQZ5GqXs-c6OzCg5oJ0QPjLWGs438Savm7HlXNyuW19VIBXkv_XOfjfDZt_mRD8NFAjkXUsq62jhfGeClCQoaNaBxelfdwWUS9vRRQUf4ejA8mQHv2Oep7EPHKsG_JEIHT7Ws2Rt5MaYl9ydAQ9wM9igi6KJFrWfxRDRzl3k6vYC8qg";

            JWTToken token = DecodeHS256Token(AccessTokenStr, "secret");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
        }


        private static JWTToken DecodeHS256Token(string jwt, string secret)
        {
            JWTToken token = new JWTToken();

            //Split the token into it's sub-parts
            string[] splitted = jwt.Split('.');
            var headerpart = splitted[0];
            var payloadpart = splitted[1];
            var TokenSignature = splitted[2];

            //Decode and deserialize the header            
            byte[] _dec = Utility.Base64UrlDecode(headerpart);
            string headerjson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_dec);
            token.Headers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(headerjson);

            //Decode and deserialize the payload            
            _dec = Utility.Base64UrlDecode(payloadpart);
            string payloadjson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_dec);
            token.Payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(payloadjson);

            token.TokenSignature = TokenSignature;

            //Calculate the expected hash using the provided secret
            string stringToSign = headerpart + "." + payloadpart;

            var alg = new HMACSHA256(Utility.getBytes(secret));
            byte[] hash = alg.ComputeHash(Utility.getBytes(stringToSign));

            var calculatedSignature = Utility.Base64UrlEncode(hash);

            if (TokenSignature == calculatedSignature)
                Console.WriteLine("Token signature match!");
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token signature don't match!");
                Console.WriteLine($"TokenSignature = {TokenSignature}");
                Console.WriteLine($"calculatedSignature = {calculatedSignature}");

            }

            return token;
        }
    }  


  public class JWTToken
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> Payload { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        public string TokenSignature { get; set; }
    }
```